# Numeric Overflow in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a numeric field in my report that I perform the operation
     `Time({Command.EndTime}/60,Remainder({Command.EndTime},60),0)` 
on.
Basically the field is a time field but my predecessor used a numeric field to represent it for some unknown reason. The field is the number of minutes past midnight. For example: 60 is 1am, 65 is 01:05 am...) I would like to report it in a form that is more human friendly. However, I got this error "Numeric overflow" and wonder what might have caused it. Normally, the cause of this error is a division by zero but the divisor is clearly 60.
If I just used {Command.EndTime}, the report was fine... The database is huge with millions of records, so scanning the report line by line is only my last resort. Is there a way to know what was wrong in the data or better yet get around the error mentioned above?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter to `Time()` has to be a whole number. Try this instead:

`Time(Truncate({Command.EndTime}/60),Remainder({Command.EndTime},60),0)`

Comment: Yep...indeed!! Thank you Ryan! very much appreciated!